# Can not submit form react-bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have the following `react-bootstrap` component:

```
        <FormGroup onSubmit={this.gotEmail} role="form">
          <FormControl type="text" className="form-control"/>
          <Button className="btn btn-primary btn-large centerButton" type="submit">Send</Button>
        </FormGroup>
```

I would like the form to be submitted when I click the button "Send".

However, if I click the button, control doesn't reach the `this.gotEmail` method.

Why is that the case?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`FormGroup` does not provide on submit event. You can wrap it with `form` element and attach event handler to it:

```
<form onSubmit={this.gotEmail}>
  <FormGroup role="form">
    <FormControl type="text" className="form-control"/>
    <Button className="btn btn-primary btn-large centerButton" type="submit">Send</Button>
  </FormGroup>
</form>
```

Comment: Just curious, whats's the use of the role="form"? For my examlpe, I've just got <FormGroup> and it works

Comment: So if I´m using <Form horizontal> as the doc says (https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#forms-horizontal), Do I have to wrap this with another form since there is no onSubmit prop and have 2 forms in my DOM?

Comment: @migueloop as of version 0.30.2, you can just use <Form horizontal onSubmit={this.gotEmail}>

Answer (score 20):

There is one thing missing, I think.

In `gotEmail`, there should be a `preventDefault`, so if the user press 'enter', the page won't reload:

```
gotEmail(event){ 
  event.preventDefault();
  // code you want to do
}
```

Answer (score 12):

As of version 0.30.2, you can wrap it in a `<Form>`, which supports the onSubmit property:

```
<Form onSubmit={this.gotEmail}>
  <FormGroup role="form">
  <FormControl type="text" className="form-control"/>
  <Button className="btn btn-primary btn-large centerButton" 
  type="submit">Send</Button>
  </FormGroup>
</Form>
```

Answer (score 3):

I've been successful with reactstrap using the following snippet:

```html
<Button onClick={this.onSubmit}>Login</Button>
```